# To display the count of rows deleted using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure that deletes rows from the Employee table. It should accept 1 parameter that is department name; only delete the employee records belonging to that department. Display how many employees were deleted else raise "DeptNotFoundException" and print the message 'No Records found.'.

```
EMPLOYEE: 
Column name  Data type      Constraints
EMP_ID       NUMBER(5)      PK
EMP_NAME     VARCHAR2(25)   NOT NULL
SALARY       NUMBER(10,2)    
DEPT         VARCHAR2(25)    
Sample Output:
2 Employee record(s) got deleted.
```

The code I tried is -

```
create or replace procedure DELETE_EMPLOYEE(v_dept IN EMPLOYEE.dept%TYPE)
is 
begin
delete EMPLOYEE where dept = v_dept;
commit;
end;
/
```

It works fine to delete the rows, but I don't know how to find the count of the deleted rows and display it in the result, please help regarding this. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: `sql%rowcount`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure DELETE_EMPLOYEE(v_dept IN EMPLOYEE.dept%TYPE)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    delete EMPLOYEE where dept = v_dept;
  5    dbms_output.put_Line('deleted ' || sql%rowcount || ' row(s)');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec delete_employee(10);
deleted 3 row(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Also, I wouldn't commit in the procedure; let the caller decide and commit (or not).

Comment: Should I use the IF_ELSE condition to raise the "DeptNotFoundException"? If so what should be the condition for IF statement?

Comment: It depends on you. The procedure will work regardless - it just won't delete anything, so you can code that into the message (e.g. if 0 rows was deleted, either department doesn't exist, or nobody works in it).

Comment: `if sql%rowcount > 0 then ...`

Comment: Yes the IF_ELSE statement worked with IF_condition `sql%found`. Thank you for help

Comment: I had a similar question to delete record but using trigger, should I post a new question for that to ask help?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that would be another question, this one is *solved*.